# React course. It won't update components, when you enter it in a form. It just add amount and date on the old title

Tags: reactjs, forms, components

React course. It won't update components, when you enter it in a form.  It just add amount and date on the old title. Component ToiletPaper,which is first, receives newly entered amount and date and old amount and date go in the component below. Title doesn't update at all. Thanks
React course. It won't update components, when you enter it in a form.  It just add amount and date on the old title. Component ToiletPaper,which is first, receives newly entered amount and date and old amount and date go in the component below. Title doesn't update at all. Thanks
React course. It won't update components, when you enter it in a form.  It just add amount and date on the old title. Component ToiletPaper,which is first, receives newly entered amount and date and old amount and date go in the component below. Title doesn't update at all. Thanks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Expenses from './component/Expenses/Expenses';
import NewExpense from './component/NewExpense/NewExpense';



  const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [
    {
      id: 'e1',
      title: 'Toilet Paper',
      amount: 94.12,
      date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
    },
    { id: 'e2', title: 'New TV', amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
    {
      id: 'e3',
      title: 'Car Insurance',
      amount: 294.67,
      date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
    },
    {
      id: 'e4',
      title: 'New Desk (Wooden)',
      amount: 450,
      date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
    },
  ];
function App(){

  const[expenses,setExpenses] = useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);
  
  const addExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
    setExpenses((prevExpenses) => {
      return [expense, ...prevExpenses];
    });
    };

    
  return (
    <div>
<NewExpense onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler}/>    
     <Expenses items={expenses}></Expenses>

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Expenses.css';
import ExpenseItem from './ExpenseItem';
import Card from '../UI/Card';
import ExpensesFilter from './ExpensesFilter';


function Expenses(props){

    const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState('2020');

    function filterChangeHandler(selectedYear){

        setFilteredYear(selectedYear);
    


    }
return (

    <div>

        
<Card className='expenses'>
<ExpensesFilter selected= {filteredYear} onChangeFilter={filterChangeHandler}
   />
   {props.items.map((expense => (
   <ExpenseItem 
   title={expense.title} 
   amount={expense.amount} 
   date={expense.date}
   />)))}

</Card>
</div>
);
}

export default Expenses;
```